# Twitter Authentication with R

Tags: r, twitter

I am following the latest update on [twitteR homepage][1], and I can't pass the authorization process. I am using Windows 8.1 and the most up to date R packages and R studio/R.
I tried disabling my firewall-- that didn't work.
I tried adding the base64enc package (some people claim that it helped them) but it didn't work. 
I need to get this right because it's my first year project for my PhD in Psychology and my adviser will really not be pleased if I can't get this to work.

```
library("base64enc")
library("twitteR")
library("ROAuth")
api_key <-  "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
api_secret <- "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
access_token <- "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
access_secret <- "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
setup_twitter_oauth(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_secret)
```

This is the output I am getting back:

```
[1] "Using direct authentication"
Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error:
This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to use an old version of the httr package.
So on the author Github, some people were saying to use the 0.6.0 version but that's actually causing more problems. By trial and error, I figured out that it's the 1.0.0 version that is necessary. Here is the line of code.
devtools::install_version("httr", version="1.0.0", repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")

P.S. I changed the keys. Those posted don't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I believe with the new release in Twitter API an OAuth handshake is necessary for every request you do. 
I have extracted tweets recently and my code below using setup_twitter_oauth() works perfectly fine. 
First you have to get your api_key and your api_secret as well as your access_token and access_token_secret from your app settings on Twitter. Just click on the “API key” tab to see them.

> consumerKey <- "xyz" consumerSecret <- "xyz" accessToken <- "xyz"
>   accessTokenSecret <- "xyz"
>
> setup_twitter_oauth(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken,
>   accessTokenSecret)

Comment: Thanks!
Am I supposed to add the last line again after this code or should I just run the code you provided (with my keys, of course)?
Sorry, I am a beginner when it comes to Twitter stuff (I'm a 1st year grad student).

Comment: I tried to use the code you supplied, but I am getting this error 
   [1] "Using direct authentication"
    Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error:
    This most likely means that you have incorrectly called     setup_twitter_oauth()'
    Even though I have the correct info.

Comment: You can just run the code I provided, after you replace the token and access details.

Comment: I did replace the toke and access details with what I have on my app profile....I don't get what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Let me have a look at your latest code and we can take it up from there...?

Comment: So apparently some people use http://127.0.0.1:1410 as the call back website in the twitter app. But when I tried to use it, it won't work either.... 
Should I send you my code with the keys in them?

Comment: You may also want to go through - http://thinktostart.com/twitter-authentification-with-r/

Comment: library("twitteR")
library("ROAuth")
library("devtools")
library("rstudioapi")
library("withr")
library("rjson")
library("bit64")
library ("httr")
download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem",destfile="cacert.pem")
consumerKey <- "cHDhB8dcWGFQQibk71BjQszi6" 
consumerSecret <- "16J2KbRDq6tWs87d0E4nXl3j1EsL4K7CoAUKcZnNgcqqrcn6D5" 
accessToken <- "465909454-NH9mNjHbQdy5zn2Y8NCMR9NH24B1JbykrMyZBbCb" 
accessTokenSecret <- "MQmuMYJziGPu5BvMK2yElkhApBomASiS8KpMVob7qV3CZ"

setup_twitter_oauth(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret)

Comment: I followed every step on that blog.

Comment: I ran following code using your access tokens and I am able to extract tweets -

Comment: library("twitteR") 
library("ROAuth") 

consumerKey <- "cHDhB8dcWGFQQibk71BjQszi6" 
consumerSecret <- "16J2KbRDq6tWs87d0E4nXl3j1EsL4K7CoAUKcZnNgcqqrcn6D5" 
accessToken <- "465909454-NH9mNjHbQdy5zn2Y8NCMR9NH24B1JbykrMyZBbCb" 
accessTokenSecret <- "MQmuMYJziGPu5BvMK2yElkhApBomASiS8KpMVob7qV3CZ" 
setup_twitter_oauth(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
              
#Extracting Tweets
India_iphone_tweets = searchTwitter('iPhone', n=5000)

Comment: For some reason, I still can't. Do I need any other packages?

Comment: Have you installed the packages using install.packages()? Please check

Comment: Again the same error--------------[1] "Using direct authentication"
Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error:
This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()'